# Unable to plot a heatmap next to a phylogenetic tree due to a scale_fill_manual error

Tags: r, ggtree

I am trying to plot a heatmap next to a phylogenetic tree and colour the heatmap according to the data. However when I attempt to plot this using ggtree in R, I get the error:   could not find function "scale_fill_manual".

I have tried several web searches to overcome the issue. I am basing my code off a previously published example: https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/plotTree-ggtree/blob/master/03_curated_genes.R

Here is an example of the phylogenetic data (a newick formatted tree file):

`(B:6.0,(A:5.0,C:3.0,E:4.0):5.0,D:11.0);`

Here is an example of the heatmap data (csv formatted file):

```
Genome Data_1 Data_2
A      1      5
B      2      5
C      2      6
D      3      7
E      4      7
```

Here is my current R script:

```
library(ggtree)
library(ape)
library(phytools) #needed for midpoint rooting

#read in tree
t<-read.tree("RAxML_bestTree.BestTree")
#midpoint root tree
rooted <- midpoint.root(t)
#ladderise midpoint rooted tree (F is false --> ascending, T is true --> descending)
tl_f <- ladderize(rooted, F)

#read in the metadata
tipcategories = read.csv("metadata.csv", 
                         sep = "\t",
                         row.names=1,
                         header = TRUE, 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
rn <- rownames(tipcategories)
heatmapData <- as.data.frame(sapply(tipcategories, as.character))
rownames(heatmapData) <- rn
head(heatmapData)

#setup colour range, need 7 different colours
heatmap.colours=c("green","red","orange","pink","purple","blue","gold")
names(heatmap.colours) <- 1:7

#plot tree
p <- ggtree(tl_f) + geom_tiplab(size=1, color="purple")
p2 <- gheatmap(p, heatmapData, offset = 2, color=NULL, colnames_position="top", 
colnames_angle=90, colnames_offset_y = 1, hjust=0, font.size=2) + 
scale_fill_manual(values=heatmap.colours,breaks=1:7)
p2
```

I expect a plot similar to plot 3 from this website: https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/plotTree-ggtree, however I get the error: 
Error in scale_fill_manual(values = heatmap.colours, breaks = 1:7) : could not find function "scale_fill_manual"

I am using R version 3.6.0, Bioconductor version 3.9 (BiocManager 1.30.4) and ggtree version 1.16.1

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: It seems don't have `ggplot2` loaded. Try `library(ggplot2)` at the very top of your script and see if that works.

Comment: Many thanks, that worked! I get a warning message saying: Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will replace the existing scale. However, it does allow me to plot the image